# Изменения в БД по расписанию

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Как можно реализовать автоматическое изменение данных в бд?
Например, в MySQL содержится определенная строка, с заданным временем.
Когда наступит это время, строка должна автоматически удалиться.

Возможно ли такое?

Заранее благодарен,
С Уважением

Comment: Так делать не принято. просто в тех случаях когда вы получаете строки из таблицы добавляйте условие что ее время еще не истекло. А сама строка при этом может оставаться в таблице. Если же вы считаете что такие строки занимают много места добавьте в cron (или другой планировщик) задание например раз в сутки удаляющее не нужные строки

Comment: у самого mysql нету такого, что бы сам обновлялся, вам нужно это реализовывать через скажем cron